# Can't pass a callback function's pointer as argument

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, callback, function-pointers

As a C++ programming beginner, I'm stuck at what it seems to be a simple issue. I can't pass a callback function pointer as argument. The `midiInOpen` function wants a `DWORD_PTR` type value for the third argument, and obviously this doesn't work :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

using namespace std;

void CALLBACK traiterMidiIn(HMIDIIN hMidiIn, UINT wMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2) {
    std::wcout << "wMsg:" << wMsg << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "dwParam1:" << dwParam1 << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "dwParam2:" << dwParam2 << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    // Set the console to unicode mode
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    // Declare variables
    BYTE byResultat;
    UINT uiNumDevice;
    MIDIINCAPS midiincaps;
    HMIDIIN hmidiin;

    // Initialize variables
    uiNumDevice = 0;

    // Open MIDI port
    byResultat = midiInOpen(&hmidiin, uiNumDevice, &traiterMidiIn, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);

    return 0;
}
```

I think this is related to member/non-member/static functions, but examples about them are still too difficult to apprehend for my weak skills yet.
The error generated :

```
l'argument de type "void (__stdcall *)(HMIDIIN hMidiIn, UINT wMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2)" est incompatible avec le paramètre de type "DWORD_PTR"
```

Comment: Cast it, as in `reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(traiterMidiIn)`

Comment: OK, thanks it works, but why in a comment instead of an answer ?

Comment: That's highly sloppy of Microsoft to not properly type that parameter.

Comment: Once you've answered the same question dozens of times the extra few rep points begin to lose their attraction :)